# Ошибки при развертывании django приложения на cервер pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Выполнял всего 2 команды:

```
$ pip3.6 install --user pythonanywhere
$ pa_autoconfigure_django.py https://github.com/<your-github-username>/my-first-blog.git(со своим github адресом конечно)
Ошибки следующие
< Running migrate database >
   \
    ~<:>>>>>>>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 87, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 212, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 73, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 56, in has_table
    return self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor())
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 256, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 20, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 52, in <module>
    main(arguments['<git-repo-url>'], arguments['--domain'], arguments['--python'], nuke=arguments.get('--nuke'))
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 43, in main
    project.run_migrate()
  File "/home/KhunovEldar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pythonanywhere/django_project.py", line 96, in run_migrate
    'migrate',
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/KhunovEldar/.virtualenvs/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/bin/python', '/home/KhunovEldar/khunoveldar.pythonanywhere.com/manage.py', 'migrate']' return
ed non-zero exit status 1.
```

```html
"""
Django settings for file_hosting project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '1$&w&o9^x9f=a=*6-%wm829f&o2-897=fcms%nxmlt-o%mion8'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [KhunovEldar.pythonanywhere.com]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
#    'django.contrib.admin',
#    'django.contrib.auth',
#    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
#    'django.contrib.sessions',
#    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'files',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
#    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
#    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
#    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
#    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'file_hosting.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                # 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'file_hosting.wsgi.application'


Database

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

 DATABASES = {
     'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
     }
 }


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

# AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
#     {
#         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
#     },
#     {
#         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
#     },
#     {
#         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
#     },
#     {
#         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
#     },
# ]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = False
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = False


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')

FILES_DIR = 'files/' # Директория, в которой мы храним загруженные через web-интерфейс файлы.
FILES_ROOT = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, FILES_DIR)
FILES_URL = MEDIA_URL + FILES_DIR
```

Comment: Лучше всего копировать код из терминала сюда, а не вставлять скриншоты. Хотя там в стектрейсе все стоит, настройки базы данных не сконфигурированы (в `DATABASES` нет ключа `ENGINE`).

Comment: как исправить данную проблему ?

Comment: Прописать `ENGINE` в `DATABASES`. Вообще, базу данных не забыл сконфигурировать? Покажи свой `settings.py` модуль. `ENGINE` определяет, с какой базой данных Django имеет дело в проекте (MySQL/postgres/sqlite/и т.д.).

Comment: добавил код пожалуйста просмотрите